# How to allow path without login on ApiPlatform?

Tags: api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony5

I have the following path:

```
  api_inventories_create_inventory_listing_collection            POST     ANY      ANY    /api/inventory/{type}
```

Its defined in my entity as follows:

```
@ApiResource(
 *     attributes={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *     "create_inventory_listing"={
 *         "method"="POST",
 *         "path"="/inventory/{type}",
 *         "controller"=CreateSingleDeviceTypeController::class,
 *     },
 *         "post"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *          "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *         "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object.owner == user"},
 *     }
 *     )
```

As you can see, in the ApiResource, that controller has no security.

And in security.yml I allowed the path:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
    - { path: ^/api/inventory, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
    - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Attached is the request via curl

```
curl -X POST 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/inventory/water' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
     --data '{"deviceType":"/api/device_types/2","serial":"provision"}'
```

and the response

```
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}
```

Comment: yes, 
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you specified security attributes on the ressource level in your entity :
 `attributes={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},`

That means their is a security, so the system will try to find a user.